# How to join two huge tables in MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I have two tables `kw` with 250000 records and `t_n` with 100000 records.
I joined both tables to get collective results in following query:

```
SELECT kw.id AS kw_id,
       kw.word AS kw_word,
       t_n.translation AS t_n_translation
FROM kw, t_n 
WHERE kw.id = t_n.keyword_id
  AND kw.word LIKE '1%' 
GROUP BY t_n.translation 
LIMIT 10
```

I also tried following simple join as an alternate of above query:

```
SELECT kw.id AS kw_id,
       kw.word AS kw_word,
       t_n.translation AS t_n_translation
FROM kw 
INNER JOIN t_n
    ON kw.id = t_n.keyword_id
   AND kw.word LIKE '1%' 
GROUP BY t_n.translation 
LIMIT 10
```

But both queries took about 60 to 150 seconds depending on the system resources of memory and processing.
This execution timeout is unbearable for extending database and increasing multiple users.
**Is there any efficient way to join two huge tables?**

**UPDATE**
This query is for JQuery UI Autocomplete. And I used GROUP BY Clause to get distinct values values. Is there any other suitable solution to get distinct values.

**Tables Structure**

```
--
-- Table structure for table `kw`
--

CREATE TABLE `kw` (
  `id` int(32) NOT NULL,
  `word` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pos` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `definition` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `t_n`
--

CREATE TABLE `t_n` (
  `id` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `keyword_id` int(16) NOT NULL,
  `translation` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `kw`
--
ALTER TABLE `kw`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `t_n`
--
ALTER TABLE `t_n`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `kw`
--
ALTER TABLE `kw`
  MODIFY `id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `t_n`
--
ALTER TABLE `t_n`
  MODIFY `id` int(16) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Could you attach the execution plan?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. For further help, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: 1) Remove GROUP BY - it is logically wrong. 2) Create according indices (I'd recommend to test `kw (word, id)` and `t_n (keyword_id, translation)`.

Comment: LIMITing without ORDERing rarely makes sense.

Comment: Your query is malformed.  The `GROUP BY` columns are not consistent with the `SELECT` columns.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Learn the basics of relational & SQL optimization/implementation/performance by query engines in general via textbooks & the web & SO & in particular via DBMS manual--all immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. Appropriate research is expected for questions. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you want:

```
SELECT kw.id as kw_id, kw.word as kw_word, t_n.translation as t_n_translation
FROM kw INNER JOIN
     t_n
     ON kw.id = t_n.keyword_id AND kw.word LIKE '1%' ;
```

For this query, you want an index on `kw(word, id)` and `t_n(keyword_id)`:

```
create index idx_kw_word_id on kw(word, id);
create index idx_t_n_keyword_id on t_n(keyword_id);
```

Comment: I tries your provided query but still taking long time. I also provided tables structure in the update of my question. I think it is due to some missing indexes as you mentioned in the last line of your answer.

Comment: @Rashid . . . You haven't added the indexes recommended in the answer.

Comment: Can you show/give me the procedure to add indexes on the fields of `kw(word,id)` and `t_n(keyword_id)`?

Comment: Superb - now query is tremendously fast after adding indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to use `JOIN ON` to say how the tables are related and `WHERE` for filtering:

```
SELECT kw.id AS kw_id,
       kw.word AS kw_word,
       t_n.translation AS t_n_translation
FROM kw 
INNER JOIN t_n
    ON kw.id = t_n.keyword_id
WHERE kw.word LIKE '1%' 
ORDER BY t_n.translation 
LIMIT 10
```

It is unclear that the `GROUP BY` is necessary or proper.  Please explain its purpose, and tell us what happens without it.  A `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is rarely meaningful.  Perhaps you meant `ORDER BY` *instead of* `GROUP BY`?  (So I made that change.)

Assuming you don't have any `TEXT` columns, these indexes should help:

```
kw:   INDEX(word, id)
t_n:  INDEX(keyword_id, translation)
```

These indexes are "composite", but that is not very relevant, and "covering", which gives a performance boost.

If I can see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, there may be further improvements, such as modifying the `PRIMARY KEY`.

**More**

`int(32)` -- the `(32)` means nothing.  `INT` is always a 32 bit (4-byte) number; `SMALLINT` is a 16-bit (2-byte) number.

It seems like `keyword_id` would be unique in `t_n`.  If so, make it the `PRIMARY KEY` and completely get rid if `id`.

At that point, it seems like the two tables could merge into one?  There are lots of distinct words, each one has a single translation?  But maybe not, since I see that the two tables are different sizes.  Please explain the schema.

Comment: . . I have provided table structure in the update of my question.

Comment: @Rashid - I added some more.

Answer (score 0):

I can to advice next solution:

1. add index:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX keyword_id_ix on t_n(keyword_id);
   ```
2. filter big table using `LIKE`:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM kw WHERE  kw.word LIKE '1%'
   ```
3. Combine result with second table using `JOIN`:

   ```
   SELECT
       kw.id as kw_id, kw.word as kw_word, t_n.translation as t_n_translation
   FROM (
       SELECT * FROM kw WHERE  kw.word LIKE '1%'
   ) kw 
   INNER JOIN t_n ON kw.id = t_n.keyword_id;
   ```

SQL fiddle [here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=c8a36ea6e0017d1ee4fd52994a4317c3&php_version=php5&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: No need for the "derived table" (subquery); just `JOIN` the two tables together.

Comment: @RickJames, sure we can to use straight JOIN without sub-query, but on big table sub-query helps to reduce data-set before join and can improve performance. Sure the solution efficiency must be tested on real data